# If I am using the coordinate system WGS84 ESPG:4326 and my cell size is 0.00833333,-0.00833333, how can I calculate the area of one cell in metres?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area

I am currently trying to undertake some area calculations on some rasters. I have them all in the coordinate system wgs84 ESPG:4326 which I have just realised is in degrees. My cell size is 0.00833333,-0.00833333. How can I figure out the cell size in metres.

Comment: You can't, since the extent of a degree in [m] varies with the latitude. 1 degree from east to west at the equator is about 110 km, but only 36 km at the polar circle.

Comment: Is there a way then to calculate the area of a raster in wgs84 ESPG:4326 in metres?

Comment: What about "you can't" is ambigous?

Comment: Nothing! I guess it needs to be converted to a projected coordinate system then?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, though it'll lead to a decrease in data accuracy. Depending on your project area you could use EPSG 3857 (global/continental scale) or a fitting UTM zone (up to 200 km width).

Comment: Okay I have begun to try that. I am using EPSG 3857 because I am mapping a large area across Central Asia and China. When I convert my raster though the cell size stays the same and therefore does not convert to metres. How can I get this to change?

Comment: Very approximately, your cell length is 1000 m, as a result your cell area will be 1000000 square meters...

Comment: No, Web Mercator is the ***last*** projection you want to use to calculate area. It is always wrong, horrifically so. Any area calculated from 3857 is useless.

Comment: Ah okay thank you Erik, Cyril, and Vince. I have begun to figure it out with your guidance!